# Mask is not allowing blank in textbox. How can I change this?

Tags: c#, devexpress, mask, textedit

I have a Devexpress TextEdit field on the screen with a numeric mask (n0).  When I delete the value in the field, I want it to just be blank, but it's being forced to be a 0.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Is the TextEdit control data bound to a property/field? If so, does this property/field allow for null values (like Nullable)? Did you set the TextEdit.Properties.AllowNullInput property?

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemTextEdit_AllowNullInputtopic

Comment: AllowNullInput works fine. However, if I am deleting digits using Backspace or Delete, trying to remove the last one always turns it into 0 first and I need another keypress to make the field blank. If I select the entire input and delete that, I get a blank field immediately. Any idea how to get rid of this minor quirk?